# \multirow in tex4ht -- in the next row extra <td> not removed and produced wrong HTML view

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, tex4ebook

In tex4HT, \multirow produced the HTML output, but the extra `<td>` element not deleted when the previous row has more rows option `(\multorow)`

I run the file through `make4ht.exe -l -a debug -u <filename>.tex` and `Texlive 2022`

How to correct the output in the TEX4HT

**LaTeX Output:**

[image]

**HTML Output:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[numbers]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Multirow table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|r|r}
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{12} & 1110.1 & a\\ % <-- Combining 2 rows with arbitrary with (*) and content 12
      &10.1 & b\\ % <-- Content of first column omitted.
      \hline
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
      4 & 25.113231 & d\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue in TeX Live 2023. I've fixed some issue with Multirow in last December, but it still should be in TL 2022. Try if this configuration helps. It is the current HTML configuration for Multirow:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{multirow}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="multirow">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]